# Vuejs CLI white page after templates error

Tags: javascript, vue.js, templates, vuejs2, vue-cli

I put this code but my page is white at the moment of i want to look my website.

I don't understand because if i delete all of this code and i keep my navigation components, i can see my Navbar.

Why my Javascript code doesn't work ?

Ps: I tried with other Javascript code and the result is the same and just before my code I had the templates error (this is for that i added div at the top and the bottom of template code )

[image]

```
<template>
<div>
  <navigation />

<div id="app">
  <div class="search-wrapper">
    <input type="text" v-model="search" placeholder="Search title.."/>
        <label>Search title:</label>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="card" v:bind="post in filteredList">
      <a v-bind:href="post.link" target="_blank">
        <img v-bind:src="post.img"/>
       <small>posted by: {{ post.author }}</small>
        {{ post.title }}
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

</template>

<script>
// @ is an alias to /src
import navigation from "@/components/navigation";
import Vue from "vue";

export default {
  components: {
    navigation
  }
};

class Post {
  constructor(title, link, author, img) {
    this.title = title;
    this.link = link;
    this.author = author;
    this.img = img;
  }
}

new Vue ({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    search: '',
    postList : [
      new Post(
        'Vue.js', 
        'https://vuejs.org/', 
        'Chris', 
        'https://vuejs.org//images/logo.png'
      ),
      new Post(
        'React.js', 
        'https://facebook.github.io/react/', 
        'Tim',
        'https://daynin.github.io/clojurescript-presentation/img/react-logo.png'
      ),
      new Post(
        'Angular.js', 
        'https://angularjs.org/', 
        'Sam', 
        'https://angularjs.org/img/ng-logo.png'
      ),
      new Post(
        'Ember.js', 
        'http://emberjs.com/', 
        'Rachel',
        'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/0cf15665a9146ba852bf042b0652780a?s=200'
      ),
      new Post(
        'Meteor.js', 
        'https://www.meteor.com/', 
        'Chris', 
        'http://hacktivist.in/introduction-to-nodejs-mongodb-meteor/img/meteor.png'
      ),
      new Post(
        'Aurelia', 
        'http://aurelia.io/', 
        'Tim',
        'https://cdn.auth0.com/blog/aurelia-logo.png'
      ),
      new Post(
        'Node.js', 
        'https://nodejs.org/en/', 
        'A. A. Ron',
        'https://code-maven.com/img/node.png'
      ),
      new Post(
        'Pusher', 
        'https://pusher.com/', 
        'Alex', 
        'https://avatars1.githubusercontent.com/u/739550?v=3&s=400'
      ),
      new Post(
        'Feathers.js', 
        'http://feathersjs.com/', 
        'Chuck',
        'https://cdn.worldvectorlogo.com/logos/feathersjs.svg'
      ),
]
  },
  computed: {
    filteredList() {
      return this.postList.filter(post => {
        return post.title.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase())
      })
    }
  }
})


</script>
```

Comment: There is no `v:bind` in Vue (it's `v-bind`). Did you mean [`v-for`](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-for)? Also, if your page is white, there should be helpful error messages in your browser's developer console (F12 in Chrome)

Comment: Hi ! I change for v-bind thank you ! If i use v-for,  I have 1 error code. My website page is stay white and I have not a error message from my console.

Comment: Seems to work fine with `v-for` for me: https://jsfiddle.net/61rvu4pL/

Answer (score 0):

`<option v-for="(size, index) in sizes" :key="index">{{ size }}</option>`

I think this type of code is the answer of my question ! I tried it and my website is not just white ;)

Thank you for the helping !